# Using ItemSource for control in ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I was trying to make universal but dynamic control for my context menus accross whole application. To do that i move ContextMenu to Window.Resources and tried to use as before before i move it. But this is not enough. 
With my current implementation i cannot use xaml to use diffrent ItemSources for diffrent ContextMenus without making another contextmenu template.

So one more time in short: Can i use ItemSource in ListView still maintainging template connection. Within Xaml. I know this would possible in c# code.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ReadOnlyContextMenuTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Menu.MenuCommands}">
        <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Text}"/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Self}"/>
                <Setter Property="InputGestureText" Value="{Binding GestureText}"/>
                <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding IconImage}">
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>
```

---

Usage

```
<ListView ContextMenu="{StaticResource ReadOnlyContextMenuTemplate}"/>
```

---

MenuCommands class

```
    public class Menu
    {
        private List<ICommand> _menuCommands;
        public List<ICommand> MenuCommands
        {
            get { return _menuCommands; }
        }

        private ICommand _commandCopy;
        public ICommand CommandCopy
        {
            get
            {
                return _commandCopy ?? (_commandCopy = new TextIconCommandHandler(
                    (parameter) => Copy(parameter), true, "Copy", "Copy.png", Key.C, ModifierKeys.Control));
            }
        }

        private ICommand _commandSelect;
        public ICommand CommandSelect
        {
            get
            {
                return _commandSelect ?? (_commandSelect = new TextIconCommandHandler(
                    (parameter) => Select(parameter), true, "Select all", "Select.png", Key.A, ModifierKeys.Control));
            }
        }

        private ICommand _commandSave;
        public ICommand CommandSave
        {
            get
            {
                return _commandSave ?? (_commandSave = new TextIconCommandHandler(
                    (parameter) => Save(parameter), true, "Save", "Save.png", Key.S, ModifierKeys.Control));
            }
        }

        public Menu()
        {
            _menuCommands = new List<ICommand>();
            var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var item in properties)
            {
                var command = item.GetValue(this, null) as ICommand;
                if(command != null)
                {
                    _menuCommands.Add(command);
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

---

TextIconCommandHandlerClass (sorry for wall of text)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace TestingTool.Commands
{
    public class CommandHandler : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> _action;
        private bool _canExecute;
        private KeyGesture _keyGesture;
        private ICommand _self;

        public ICommand Self
        {
            get { return _self; }
            set { _self = value; }
        }

        public KeyGesture KeyGesture
        {
            get { return _keyGesture; }
            set { _keyGesture = value; }
        }

        public string GestureText
        {
            get { return _keyGesture.GetDisplayStringForCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture); }
        }

        public CommandHandler(Action<object> action, bool canExecute, Key key = Key.None, ModifierKeys keysModifier = ModifierKeys.None)
        {
            _self = this;
            _action = action;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
            _keyGesture = new KeyGesture(key, keysModifier);       
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _action(parameter);
        }
    }

    public class TextCommandHandler : CommandHandler
    {
        private string _text;

        public string Text
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set { _text = value; }
        }

        public TextCommandHandler(Action<object> action, bool canExecute, string text, Key key = Key.None, ModifierKeys keysModifier = ModifierKeys.None)
            : base(action, canExecute, key, keysModifier)
        {
            _text = text;
        }
    }

    public class TextIconCommandHandler : TextCommandHandler
    {
        private string _iconName;
        private Image _iconImage;

        public Image IconImage
        {
            get { return _iconImage; }
            set { _iconImage = value; }
        } 

        public TextIconCommandHandler(Action<object> action, bool canExecute, string text, string iconName, Key key = Key.None, ModifierKeys keysModifier = ModifierKeys.None)
            : base(action, canExecute, text, key, keysModifier)
        {
            _iconName = "Resources/" + iconName;
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.UriSource = new Uri(_iconName, UriKind.Relative);
            bi.EndInit();
            _iconImage = new Image();
            _iconImage.Source = bi;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I know this would possible in c# code"_ -- maybe your question would be more understandable if, as part of your good [mcve] you showed exactly how you _would_ do this in C# code. As stated, there seems to be a lot of irrelevant code above, and not a complete enough example to know what you're trying to do. It seems to me that if you have a specific `Menu` object in mind for a given context menu, you should bind to that specific object. Where is `Menu.MenuCommands` coming from in your example above? Why can't you just set `Menu` to a different/appropriate object as needed?

Answer (score 0):

Use a standard name for your ViewModel property which will be used as ItemsSource for ContextMenu for various controls.